# Is there any way to use cloudinarydotnet or Cloudinary for .net nuget package in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, image-upload, cloudinary

I want  to Upload Images Captured by CameraCaptureService(Cimalino.Phone.Toolkit.Camera)  in windows Phone 8 to Cloudinary  , I tried to use  [CloudinaryDotNet Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CloudinaryDotNet) but it doesn't Support windows Phone 8 . So i tried to use the [Cloudinary Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cloudinary/)
, it got Installed but can't use the reference in  the project . Is there any alternative way to Upload the images to [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_integration#getting_started_guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the [Windows Phone Helper Class](http://cloudbase.io/blog/tag/storage/) has made it possible for images to upload to `Cloudinary`.

Additional reference:

[Win Phone 8 / Asp .Net Web API Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192638/)